# Room DB error ,Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, kotlin, insert, android-room, sql-delete

[image]**error:** Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Long> continuation);
^
**error:** Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
public abstract java.lang.Object insertBillProduct(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

I build, rebuild, cleaned my project, invalidate cache and restart but nothing worked

Comment: May be your sql syntax is not correct for insertBillProduct ones check it.

Comment: @Insert
    suspend fun insertBillProduct(billProduct: BillProduct): Long ,  please check this .  This worked before.

Comment: can you share code then we identify where are you doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `BillProduct` to see if it is notated with @Entity or not. Also check other method in your DAOs to make sure all the parameters typed is notated with @Entity